# Radiobutton seleccionar opción en Laravel

Tags: laravel, checkbox, radiobutton

Estoy confuso al tener que marcar un radiobutton que seleccionó el usuario, lo estoy realizando de la siguiente manera, pero no encuentro cuál es el problema por el cuál no queda seleccionado. Agradecería mucho una orientación.

```
@foreach($resultadosCategorias as $categoria)
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="rbCategoria" id="rb-categoria" value="{{ $categoria->nombre_categoria }}"  {{ ($categoria->nombre_categoria == $categoria) ? 'checked' : '' }}>

    <label class="form-check-label" for="rb-categoria">
        {{ $categoria->nombre_categoria }}
    </label>

    <br>
@endforeach
```

La siguiente condición trae los valores:

```
{{ ($categoria->nombre_categoria == $categoria) ? 'checked' : '' }}

Si imprimo {{ $categoria }} el valor es: Alquiler 

Si imprimo {{ $categoria->nombre_categoria }} el valor es: Alquiler
```

$categoria = $request->get('categoria'); (String)

$resultadosCategorias = Category::get(); (Objeto)

¿Como puedo comparar los valores?

Comment: Estás comparando un `string` con un `objeto`, por eso no se cumple la condición.

Comment: Y como podría hacer un cast? muchas gracias @L.Flor

Comment: No se trata de un casteo. Debes mostrar cómo obtienes las categorías seleccionadas por un usuario desde tu controlador. Imagino que envías ambos, categorías en general y por otro lado sólo las seleccionadas.

Comment: @L.Flor voy comprendiendo, edite la pregunta. No se puede comparar así: $categoria = array($request->get('categoria'));?? muchas gracias

Comment: Estoy buscando y no encuentro como debería hacer este procedimiento: Convertí el string a objeto, El objeto a string y no me lo reconoce. Probé el serialize y tampoco.

Comment: En qué tabla almacenas las categorías que un usuario seleccionó?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111692/discussion-between-l-flor-and-maraet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas nombrando a dos variables con el mismo nombre: `$categoría`. Dicha variable se sobrescribe al entrar al `@foreach` y toma el valor de objeto, por ello la comparación no es satisfactoria.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu inmensa ayuda @L. Flor !!